# How can I get output like "<% name %>" with ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want to produce output like `<% name %>` which is for Backbone.js template with EJS. I can use

```
<%- "<%= name %>" %>
```

to solve it, but I think it makes some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

EJS has no way to escape open and close tags. You can specify another open and close tags like `{{` and `}}` that not confused with another document content.